# Remove staged changes from old commit via rebase

Tags: git

I accidentally added staged files to a past commit (HEAD~10) via an interactive rebase (edit -> `--amend`).

Is there a simple way to undo this action?

Comment: Are you *still in* the rebase, or did you let it run to completion?

Comment: I'd be interested in solutions to both cases.
Even in a running rebase I cannot go back to a past commit (also dont show anymore in `git rebase --edit-todo`) nor can I un-amend from the current commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to undo this action?

This depends in part how far you are along, and in part on how you define *simple*.

The most important thing to know and remember about *all* rebase operations, interactive or not, is that they involve copying commits.  See my answer to [How do I process a specific merge conflict with a given strategy when rebasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68939330/1256452)

#### Stopping or undoing a rebase

If a rebase has gone wrong and you're still in the middle of it, you can terminate the whole thing quickly and easily with `git rebase --abort`.  Since the rebase process cannot (and therefore did not) alter any of the original commits, and it hadn't finished yet, *nothing has really changed* and the `--abort` just cleans out Git's index and your working tree, and puts you back into a clean state from before you started the rebase.<sup>1</sup>

If you've *finished* the rebase, and then realize that it went wrong, and have not made any new commits (and aren't using autostash so that your state is now "clean"), you can make use of the current branch's reflog, or the special name `ORIG_HEAD`, to make it look like you never started the rebase:

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

for instance.

---

<sup>1</sup>Not mentioned in my other answer from the link above, but worth considering, is how the autostash option works for rebase.  Aborting should auto-pop the auto-stash as part of the cleanup, which means that you're in the same state (clean or dirty) that you were at the start.  If you don't have autostash turned on, rebase won't allow you to start unless the state is clean.  "Clean" and "dirty" are not the best-defined terms in Git, but they tend to be fairly obvious with rebase, at least.

---

#### Undoing one already-made copy

Your text description is a bit sketchy:

> via an interactive rebase (edit -> `--amend`)

but let's assume the command sequence was:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10
<replace at least one `pick` in the instruction sheet with `edit`>
<write instruction sheet and exit editor>
<rebase begins, copies some number of commits, and then stops
 after copying the one marked edit>
```

At this point, you're in detached HEAD mode, having copied some number of commits.  Because this is an *in-place* rebase,<sup>2</sup> Git may have used some short-cuts to *preserve original commits*, so the picture could be:

```
...--C--D   (HEAD~10)
         \
          E--F--G--H--I-...-N   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

when we start, and:

```
...--C--D--E--F--G   <-- HEAD
                  \
                   H--I-...-N   <-- branch
```

when Git stops for editing.  Or, perhaps we did something (such as change author name or use the `--no-ff` option to rebase) so that we have:

```
...--C--D--E'-F'-G'  <-- HEAD
         \
          E--F--G--H--I-...-N   <-- branch
```

It's not really crucial one way or the other, it's just something to note when we draw the picture.

Anyway, at this point we have, in Git's index (AKA "the staging area") and our working tree, all the files from commit `G`, which may or may not now also exist as commit `G'`.  You then edit some working-tree file(s) and run `git add` on the file(s), and then `git commit --amend`.  What *this* does is produce yet another copy of commit `G`, this time with your updated index file(s):

```
                G"  <-- HEAD
               /
...--C--D--E--F--G
                  \
                   H--I-...-N   <-- branch
```

or:

```
                G"   <-- HEAD
               /
...--C--D--E'-F'-G'
         \
          E--F--G--H--I-...-N   <-- branch
```

The fact that there *might* be a `G'` is why I called this `G"`: if there isn't a `G'` copy of `G`, calling this `G"` is not harmful (other than maybe to our mental health, but if we were worried about that, would we be using Git? ).

If this was a *mistake*, and you want to get rid of `G"`, it's just a matter of making `HEAD` point back to commit `G` or `G'`, whichever it named a moment ago—and that commit is in the `HEAD` reflog, in position `{1}`, so:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

will put us back to whichever picture is appropriate.  Commit `G"` remains in the repository while it is findable through the `HEAD` reflog, and then eventually expires for real and vanishes once `git gc` gets around to that.

If you've built new commits *atop* `G"`, however, things are harder.  You can, in theory, figure out where to reset `HEAD` to, then do any cherry-picking that might be required to copy commits that got copied atop `G"`, if there are any such.  But at this point it's probably easiest to abort out of the rebase entirely.

---

<sup>2</sup>By *in-place*, I mean that the `--onto` target of the rebase is the same commit named as the *`upstream`* argument, which tells Git which commits *not* to copy.  That is, `git rev-parse HEAD~10` would give us the `--onto` target, which wasn't specified and thus defaulted to the *`upstream`* argument of `HEAD~10`.  The first commit *not* to copy was thus `HEAD~10`, which means we've copied commit `HEAD~9`, for instance, so that it comes after `HEAD~10`.  But it already comes after `HEAD~10`: so we changed nothing about the commit's position.  And the new snapshot matches the old snapshot, so we changed nothing about the commit's content.  The only thing that might change is the rest of the commit's metadata: author, committer, etc.  If all that can remain the same, Git can take a short-cut and just re-use the original commit in place.

---

#### Aborting a rebase while keeping a copy of what you have done so far

Suppose we start a rebase—maybe not even an in-place interactive rebase; maybe we're doing something like rebasing `topic` onto `main`:

```
          G--H--I   <-- topic (HEAD)
         /
...--E--F--J--K--L   <-- main
```

with the goal of ending up with:

```
          G--H--I   [abandoned]
         /
...--E--F--J--K--L   <-- main
                  \
                   G'-H'-I'  <-- topic (HEAD)
```

Things may start sort of OK, but after we've copied `H` to `H'` with a lot of effort, we reach the `I`-to-`I'` copy (which stops after copying due to `edit`, or while copying due to conflict) and decide that, while half or so of the work we did so far is *usable*, it's going to be better to start over.  But we'd like to save what we have so far:

```
          G--H--I   <-- topic
         /
...--E--F--J--K--L   <-- main
                  \
                   G'-H'  <-- HEAD
```

The simple thing to do is *create a new branch right here right now*.  For instance:

```
git branch topic.alt
```

If there are merge conflicts, and we're too lazy or stymied to fix them but want to save them for some reason, we can `git add` the conflicted files anyway and commit to add commit `I'` (we can do this before or after creating `topic.alt` but if we do it after we need to forcibly drag `topic.alt` forward with `git branch -f topic.alt`, so probably best to do it before creating `topic.alt`).  Then we run:

```
git rebase --abort
```

and we're back to:

```
          G--H--I   <-- topic (HEAD)
         /
...--E--F--J--K--L   <-- main
                  \
                   G'-H'  <-- topic.alt
```

(add `I'` if appropriate).  We now have a *branch name* for our commits: the ones that we had planned as new-and-improved replacements, but which turned out to be too complicated for some reason.  But this also means we can restart the `git rebase`, and this time, we can use `topic.alt~1` to look at commit `G'`, and `topic.alt` to look at commit `H'`.  We can use `git restore` to extract specific files from those specific commits, or `git show` to view a commit as a diff, or `git cherry-pick`, or whatever we like: the entire Git tool suite is there, *and* we have a name we can remember, without having to type in random-looking hash IDs.

Note that you can use a tag name instead of a branch name, if you like.  There's no particular reason to prefer one or the other, other than your own personal preferences and how you personally tend to run `git push` (if you `git push --tags` a lot, you might want to avoid tag names).